# Why does ESLint report a @typescript/no-redeclare error for a merged interface & variable?

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

My .eslintrc.json file looks like this:

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "no-redeclare": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/no-redeclare": [
      "error",
      {
        "ignoreDeclarationMerge": true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have this code (runnable [here](https://typescript-eslint.io/play/#ts=5.0.2&jsx=true&sourceType=script&code=PTAECUFMEMGMBdQBsCWAjATtDBPUBneAVzVAFpQUBzAOwHsNIAoG6AW0nwAc5IIYEoAN5NQoSAA8uDRPBxc+AMQDCAHgAqAPlABeUOtAAfUNBo4mAXyZMQoejTKTpGeJAAmd9px6xmrDty8oIp0dMKioLZOMu6UNK4YAGa8EdEucQnJvqAAChh0XPjhYmKJoQBcBPAYKDRUANwRVlY2YKjxtVTiGPkYoIDIBAAFAEQA5CF0o5RF0EiM0G54bpCJte4AdMNMaYiwdDSEwRX8cPDrKqoT63kF+Np6ABRCoGVhFgCUutoiYozEGDQXqFGhZGkA&eslintrc=N4KABGBEBOCuA2BTAzpAXGUEKQHYHsBaaRAE0QGN4BDE9KfAM0cgBpxtIABAFwE8ADigrQAlgJ6EU8Ubh4B6AsTKUadDAG0O2KImjR80NtuxYdnUQHMCJACKra1HqPy4AsnsuJ6POIhMQAL4mALocwcFAA&tsconfig=N4KABGBEDGD2C2AHAlgGwKYCcDyiAuysAdgM6QBcYoEEkJemy0eAcgK6qoDCAFutAGsylBm3TgwAXxCSgA)):

```js
import React from 'react';

namespace Foo {
  // exported interface
  export interface Props {
    foo: string;
  }
}

export const Foo: React.FC<Foo.Props> = ({ foo }) => {
  return foo;
};
```

When the code is linted, it yields the following error

```
'Foo' is already defined. 10:14 - 10:38
```

According to [`typescript-eslint` docs](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-redeclare/), I need to disable the base rule (see line 3 of the config file) and set `ignoreDeclarationMerge` to `true` (see line 7 of the config file).

Why is this still throwing an error?

---

**EDIT:** Note that this does *not* throw an error, as it is a `function` and not a `const`:

```js
export function Foo({ foo }): React.FC<Foo.Props> {
  return foo;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ignoreDeclarationMerge` only works for the following cases:

> interface + interface
> namespace + namespace
> class + interface
> class + namespace
> class + interface + namespace
> function + namespace
> enum + namespace

It won't work for namespace + variable

Comment: Also known as "[rtfm](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-redeclare/#ignoredeclarationmerge)." Thanks @Dimava!